# Scrollable div inside flex item

Tags: css

Trying to make a scrollable div inside flex-item. Edit-section here should be scrollable if content goes beyond viewport. Everything is ok in Edge and Firefox, but Chrome ignores `max-height: 100%`. How can I achieve the desired behavior?

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0">
<div id="root" style="height: 100vh; font-size: 100px">
 <div id="form" style="max-height: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: nowrap;">
  <div id="header" style="background-color: red; margin-bottom: 1px">header</div>
  <div id="form-body" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative">
   <div id="edit-section" style="overflow-y: scroll; max-height: 100%">
    <div><textarea rows="10"></textarea></div>
    <div><textarea rows="10"></textarea></div>
    <div><textarea rows="10"></textarea></div>
    <div><textarea rows="10"></textarea></div>
    <div><textarea rows="10"></textarea></div>
    <div><textarea rows="10"></textarea></div>
    <div><textarea rows="10"></textarea></div>
    <div><textarea rows="10"></textarea></div>
    <div><textarea rows="10"></textarea></div>
    <div><textarea rows="10"></textarea></div>
    <div><textarea rows="10"></textarea></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using height of a child element and you want an overflow on that element - you need to apply a height to the parent element. Remember that heights of children elements are based on the container that they sit in.

Also - it is bettewr to not use inline styling- but separate your CSS into its own file and import that into the docuemnt.

```css
html, body ,#root {
  height: 100vh; font-size: 100px; overflow: hidden
}


#form {
  height: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

#header {
  background-color: red; margin-bottom: 1px
}


#form-body {
  overflow: hidden; position: relative;height: 100%;
}

#edit-section {
 overflow-y: scroll; height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
 <div id="form" >
  <div id="header">header</div>
  <div id="form-body">
   <div id="edit-section">
    <div><textarea rows="10"></textarea></div>
    <div><textarea rows="10"></textarea></div>
    <div><textarea rows="10"></textarea></div>
    <div><textarea rows="10"></textarea></div>
    <div><textarea rows="10"></textarea></div>
    <div><textarea rows="10"></textarea></div>
    <div><textarea rows="10"></textarea></div>
    <div><textarea rows="10"></textarea></div>
    <div><textarea rows="10"></textarea></div>
    <div><textarea rows="10"></textarea></div>
    <div><textarea rows="10"></textarea></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, gavgrif. The problem here however is that I want edit-section to shrink if its content is fewer than viewport. In case of `height: 100%` it always fills the entire space.

Comment: tweaked it a little bit. Made form height: 100%. But switched to max-height attribute for form-body and edit-section. Got the desired result.